# Faceted search filter Hybris products for a category not displaying on storefront

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I have a requirement whereby I want to display products for a category and some search `criteria` on the front end for out of the box. I created a category and added products to it.

I performed an indexing and it is visible on Solr,under the product.

However after hitting: `/mystorefront/c/{mycategory}`

it is throwing a "Server Error",and not displaying products on the storefront. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Please add console log for you `server error`

Comment: What I understand is, you are not able to open the category(newly created) from the storefront. Are you able to open any existing (OOTB) category?